# Why I can't move the content of a directory (including hidden files) to a file using only echo?

Tags: files, echo

I have a directory named `Musique` and I want to have the list of files saved to `nom.txt` using ONLY `echo`.

However I also want to copy the directory's hidden files and separate them from the "normal" files of the directory with a line break (`\n`).

I tried these commands but it doesn't work and I don't know why they don't work ? :

```
echo -e Musique/ \n.* > nom.txt
echo -e \n.* Musique/ > nom.txt
echo -e /Musique \n.* > nom.txt
```

Can someone explain me? Thanks

Comment: Please [edit] your question and clarify what you mean. Show us the output of `ls -la  Musique/` (or just a few lines, if it is large) and then show us what you expect to see in `nom.txt`. You cannot copy files into a file, so I think you mean you just want to have the list of files saved to `nom.txt`.

Comment: Why `echo`? `echo` can't be used to output arbitrary data.

Comment: This sounds like a [X Y problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: When i do ls -la Musique/                                                                                                             drwxrwxr-x  2 sarah sarah 4096 Oct  7 12:14 .
drwxr-x--- 19 sarah sarah 4096 Oct  7 12:13 ..
-rw-rw-r--  1 sarah sarah   0 Oct  7 12:13 Journal1
-rw-rw-r--  1 sarah sarah   0 Oct  7 12:13 Journal2
-rw-rw-r--  1 sarah sarah  0 Oct  7 12:14 Journal.txt
-rw-rw-r--  1 sarah sarah  0 Oct  7 12:14 Premiers.txt

Comment: I see it as a question because I don't understand why my commands doesn't work?

Comment: In that case, the question is "Why does not this work?", not "How can I do this using only `echo`?".  See also `find Musique` or `find Musique -type f`.

Comment: @SarahElAnnabi please ***[EDIT]*** your question as requested and add the new information there.

Comment: Also, please explain what "did not work" means. The commands work, they just don't do what you expect them to do. However, since we don't know what you expect, it's hard to answer. Is the problem that the file only has the output of the last command you ran?

Answer (score -2):

If I understand you correctly, until further information, you can use this command:

```
$ LC_ALL=C ls -1Ar | sed '0,/^\./s/^\./\n./' > nom.txt
$ cat nom.txt
b.txt
c.txt

.foo
.bar
```

Answer (score -2):

The unquoted two-character substring `\n` is changed by the shell to `n`, which means that each of your `echo` command lines will print the string `n.*` to the file `nom.txt`, preceded by or followed by the string `Musique/` (or `/Musique`).  If you have files in the current directory that matches the pattern `n.*`, then the command will give those files to `echo`.

Since you are using `echo -e`, presumably in `bash`, any name given as an argument containing a C escape sequence, such as `\n` or `\t`, would be modified by `echo` before printing.

You don't say, but it is fair to assume that what you want is not specifically a command line with `echo`.  Instead, it looks like you want to list the pathnames, of both hidden and non-hidden names, both of directories and other files, from the directory `Musique`, including the directory name itself.

Listing all pathnames under a directory is easiest done using `find`.

```bsh
find Musique
```

The command above would recursively walk the given search path and output each found pathnames on a line of its own.  Would you want to stop `find` from recursing into subdirectories, add `-maxdepth 1` to the end of the command (assuming you are using a recent `find` implementation, e.g., on a Linux system).

Doing this for non-hidden name only,

```bsh
find Musique ! -name '.*'
```

or only for hidden names,

```bsh
find Musique -name '.*'
```

Would you want the pathnames on a single line, delimited by spaces, then pipe the result of `find` to `paste`.

```bsh
find Musique -maxdepth 1 | paste -s -d ' ' -
```

Note that the generated list of pathnames is useless on its own, other than for looking at.  It would, for example, be challenging to tell filenames apart reliably, given that filenames on Unix systems may contain spaces, tabs, and newlines.

If you want to do something with each pathname, you would typically do so from the `find` command, using its `-exec` predicate.

Answer (score -3):

I guess you want something like this :

```
echo -e Musique/* '\n' Musique/.* >nom.txt
```

Comment: In what sense does this work better than what the user is already trying? If you think what "does not work" means, then mention how your answer solves that.

Comment: On `echo -e Musique/ \n.*`, there is just `Musique/` printed and not the included files. `Musique/*` should be used instead. The `.*` should not be closed to the `\n`. If not, the shell understands all file starting by `\n.`  I guess there are none.

Comment: Thank you! It worked.

Comment: So my mistake was that I forgot to put the name of the directory before the .*

Comment: Note that this would write out the globbing patterns unexpanded if either one of them don't match anything.